# How to build erlang dependency with rebar and make at once in Elixir project

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I wrote a erlport wrapper for elixir, but have a problem to compile erlport as a dependency. You can find it here: https://github.com/fazibear/export

Export mix.exs file:

```
defp deps do
  [
    {:erlport, git: "https://github.com/hdima/erlport.git", compile: "rebar compile && make"},
    {:ex_doc, "~> 0.11", only: :dev},
    {:earmark, ">= 0.0.0", only: :dev}
  ]
end
```

And another project that uses this package. When I add a package to this project like this:

```
defp deps do
  [
    {:export, path: "/Users/bla/dev/export"}
  ]
end
```

and invoke `mix compile` it runs just fine. Erlport compiles correctly with rebar and make.

Problem starts when I try to add project from hex.

```
defp deps do
  [
    {:export, "~> 0.0.6"}
  ]
end
```

Elport wont compile. As you can see in latest commits I tried a few combinations of `manager` and `compile` parameter in export mix file, but nothing works.

How can I compile this lib dependency ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

[Hex manual](https://hex.pm/docs/publish)

It seems, that just having rebar config file in dependency should work out of the box. Also, remember that for runtime dependencies you also need to add them to applications, not only deps.